# How to strong-type an integer in C++?

Tags: c++

Consider this C++ code snippet:

```
using BookID = int;
using CustomerID = int;

BookID bookId;
CustomerID custId;

void sub() {
   bookId = custId;
}
```

This code compiles fine. However, I would like the compiler to flag this as an error that an instance of one id type is being assigned into another.

Is there a simple way to use the power of C++ (perhaps using a generic template) that:

1. Ensures that the compiler can flag this as an error
2. Is easy to use by any developer on the team
3. Hopefully does not have much runtime overhead

On my current project, I am dealing with about 15 different ID types. Regards.

Comment: There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0109r0.pdf) for this, but for now I think you'll have to write it yourself. It's a fair bit of boilerplate, but not too difficult.

Comment: What about wrapping the `int` with _real_ classes instead of just a `typeder` or `using`? I think there shouldn't be any problem to create a class that behaves like an `int` but would be incompatible to work with another class doing the same, as long no implicit conversion operations to and from `int` are supported.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In addition, arithmetic operations like `+` are probably not appropriate for an identifier either. Which makes the real class significantly easier to implement, and prevents a number of possible misuses.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use simple `template` `struct` and extend it if necessary (make id private with accessor, ctor etc etc):

```
enum IdType {
    Book,
    Customer
};
 
template <IdType Type>
struct Id {
    int m_id;
};

using BookId = Id<Book>;
using CustomerId = Id<Customer>;
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/rz3ubx)

You can use tag types instead of `enum` values that would make it more flexible but probably less organized - your id types can be defined locally instead of forcing to enumerate all types one place:

```
template <typename T>
struct Id {
    int m_id;
};

struct BookIdTag;
using BookId = Id<BookIdTag>;
```

(thanks to @N.Shead)

Comment: Rather than using a separate enum of types, you could instead use tag types, e.g. `struct BookIdTag; using BookId = Id<BookIdTag>;` This means that the set of "strong typedefs" can be extended in other places.

Comment: @N.Shead thanks, added your suggestion into the answer

Comment: I don't think tag types make it less organized at all. If you want to enforce the tags being enumerated in one place, then you declare them all in a dedicated namespace. The `Id` template instantiations referring to tags declared in a specific namespace, won't be compatible with instantiation defined with tags of the same names without using that namespace. Very well organized. I think that's the best solution in every aspect.

Comment: @RadoslavVoydanovich I don't think there's a "best". If you want to restrict the number of id types to a fixed set of types, then the `enum` solution is better. If you want to make it open, so that anyone can add a new id type anywhere, then the tag solution is best. Depending on the application, one or the other is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Per cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

> An enumeration can be initialized from an integer without a cast, using list initialization, if all of the following are true:
>
> the initialization is direct-list-initialization
>
> the initializer list has only a single element
>
> the enumeration is either scoped or unscoped with underlying type fixed
>
> the conversion is non-narrowing
>
> This makes it possible to introduce new integer types (e.g. SafeInt) that enjoy the same existing calling conventions as their underlying integer types, even on ABIs that penalize passing/returning structures by value.

This allows you to make strong integer types using enums, like this:

```cpp
enum BookID : int {};
enum CustomerID : int {};
```

And initialize them from integers using direct-list-initialization like this:

```cpp
BookID book{0};
CustomerID customer{0};

customer = book; // Generates a compile error.
```

A potential downside is that you'll have to explicitly cast to get the integer back out of the strong type, if you ever need to.

Answer (score 1):

Since `using` and `typedef` are basically just aliases, your `BookID` and `CustomerID` are really the same type - `int`.  The only way to make them distinct types is to wrap them in a `struct` or `class`, eg:

```cpp
class BookID
{
    int id;
public:
    explicit BookID(int id = 0) : id(id) {}
    explicit operator int() const { return id; }
};

class CustomerID
{
    int id;
public:
    explicit CustomerID(int id = 0) : id(id) {}
    explicit operator int() const { return id; }
};
```

```cpp
BookID bookId;
CustomerID custId;

void sub()
{
   bookId = custId; // <-- fails!
}
```

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘BookID’ and ‘CustomerID’)

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/9aHWFx)

You could avoid the code duplication using a template, eg:

```cpp
template <size_t>
class intWrapper
{
    int value;
public:
    explicit intWrapper(int value = 0) : value(value) {}
    explicit operator int() const { return value; }
};

using BookID = intWrapper<1>;
using CustomerID = intWrapper<2>;
```

```cpp
BookID bookId;
CustomerID custId;

void sub()
{
   bookId = custId; // <-- fails!
}
```

> error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘BookID’ {aka ‘intWrapper<1>’} and ‘CustomerID’ {aka ‘intWrapper<2>’})

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/HPikvV)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This almost works. Except that it breaks on == operator.

Comment: As it should be.  The wrapper would have to manually implement every `operator` that you want it to support, including `==`, eg: `class BookID { ... public: bool operator==(const BookID &rhs) const { return id == rhs.id; } };` ... `template <size_t> class intWrapper { ... public: bool operator==(const intWrapper &rhs) const { return value == rhs.value; } };`

Comment: Hi Remy. Adding the == operator on the template doesn't seem to help. The code "if (bookId == custId) {} still compiles.

Comment: That can happen if `bookId` and `custId` are *implicitly* convertible to the same type. That is not the case in the examples I have given you, as *implicit* conversions are disabled by the `explicit` keywords. [This fails](https://ideone.com/V1xvD5) (`error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘BookID’ and ‘CustomerID’)`), and [this fails](https://ideone.com/aMrXSh) (`no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘BookID’ {aka ‘intWrapper<1>’} and ‘CustomerID’ {aka ‘intWrapper<2>’})`)  Are you, by chance, using an older compiler that doesn't support `explicit` on conversion operators?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, I know, but for future reference: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/12/08/strong-types-for-strong-interfaces/ is a blog series about the idea of using stronger types in C++, where indeed a CustomerId and a BookId are not the same thing, even if they both use an int as the underlying type.

https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType is a project that provides a universal wrapper type to achieve this, allowing you to say:

```
using CustomerId = NamedType<int, struct CustomerIdTag>;
```

You can choose which operations you want to enable on the type, by adding additional tags:

```
using Meter = NamedType<unsigned long long, struct MeterParameter, Addable, Comparable>;
```

This then enables the ability to compare and to add this type. Many other operators and methods are available to be made available in this way.